# FB messenger webview restrict users from visiting the URL if outside of messenger

Tags: webview, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a webview that is accessible even if outside of messenger.

I saw a webview that restricts users if it's opened outsied of messenger: 
https://victoria-belle.herokuapp.com/.
A sample chatbot is the "Victoria Belle" when you choose "Set Gift Preferences", it only opens inside messenger app.

How can I make my webview private?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the "signed_request" confirmation to the backend of your webview website. So you will know that the user came from the Messenger.
More details about signed_request confirmation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/context#signed)